# How can I change all items of one colour in Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a document with text and borders in a fuchsia type colour. The RGB colour was determined using a ColorPicker tool in Gimp, and then those RGB values used for a custom text colour in the Word document.

There are many separate items with this custom colour. Is there a way to make the custom colour darker for all items in the document, or simply to make the fuchsia colour print darker or more intense when I print it?

Comment: You can easily search for all text of a particular colour (expand Find dialog, use Format button), but for borders etc. maybe it's possible to use a macro/VBA.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can, maybe. I did this with Word 2010. Here are the steps:

1. Press Ctrl-H, and click the More button in the Find and Replace dialog. Click the find tab.
2. Click the Format button, and select Font.
3. Select the color to be changed—leaving all else blank—and click OK.
4. Click the Replace tab, and repeat steps 2 and 3 to select the new color.
5. Click Replace All.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it's not possible to simply change a color so that every item that has that color assigned is changed.

I would assign styles to the different items in your document and assign the color in the style. That way you don't always have to go to look for every item and change it, but change the color in the styles.

To get an idea of how to work with styles, see here:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/style-basics-in-word-HA010230882.aspx#BM4
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/make-changes-to-a-quick-style-set-HA010201147.aspx

Unfortunately the colors that you set in Word are mostly not the same that you get printed out. That's because your monitor uses RGB color space ([additive color mixing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color)) and your printer uses CMYK color space ([subtractive color mixing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color)).

[image]

Not all the colors that you can see on your screen can be printed, because your screen mixes the color with light and your printer with ink.

So to make the fuchsia color more intense in the sense of brighter or more luminous will not be possible to that extent that you would have on your screen. To make it darker is no problem.

It depends on the printer how well it can replicate a color. Cheaper printers often produce desaturated colors.